# Google play store Native Crash

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-console

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/x1quex/x1q:10/QP1A.190711.020/G981U1UEU1BTIF:user/release-keys'
Revision: '14'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-08-30 06:31:27-0700
pid: 2013, tid: 2586, name: MTC  >>> /vendor/bin/hw/rild <<<
uid: 1001
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x41435f4552555c
    x0  4d41435f45525554  x1  0000006fe35384e8  x2  0000006fe3538588  x3  0000000000000003
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  4d20ffffffffffff  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000800000000000
    x8  4145465f474e4954  x9  c93e332e251db2e7  x10 0000006fe35385c0  x11 000000000000001c
    x12 0101010101010101  x13 0000000000000001  x14 0000000000000004  x15 00005c06f5bf6939
    x16 00000070adb6e358  x17 00000070ad8531bc  x18 0000006fe274e000  x19 4d41435f45525554
    x20 00000070ac53700c  x21 0000006fe3539020  x22 00000070ac53700c  x23 0000006fe3538dd8
    x24 0000006fe3538d50  x25 0000006fe3538d50  x26 0000006fe3539020  x27 00000070aed87020
    x28 0000000000000003  x29 0000006fe3538b20
    sp  0000006fe3538b10  lr  00000070ac3db2b4  pc  00000070ac3db314
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000037c314  /vendor/lib64/libsec-ril.so (HidtUtilsMonitor::CloseEpoll()+16) (BuildId: 74ae01d0f6b43f80ed144b79bfe704e4)
      #01 pc 000000000037c2b0  /vendor/lib64/libsec-ril.so (HidtUtils::Stop()+84) (BuildId: 74ae01d0f6b43f80ed144b79bfe704e4)
      #02 pc 00000000002aa20c  /vendor/lib64/libsec-ril.so (DataCallManager::Finalize()+380) (BuildId: 74ae01d0f6b43f80ed144b79bfe704e4)
      #03 pc 000000000022cfa0  /vendor/lib64/libsec-ril.so (EventScheduler::RemoveAllHandlers()+128) (BuildId: 74ae01d0f6b43f80ed144b79bfe704e4)
      #04 pc 0000000000238890  /vendor/lib64/libsec-ril.so (SecRil::ChangeModelTypeOnRatChange(RadioTechnology)+644) (BuildId: 74ae01d0f6b43f80ed144b79bfe704e4)
      #05 pc 00000000002392d4  /vendor/lib64/libsec-ril.so (ModelTypeChangerRunnable::Run()+204) (BuildId: 74ae01d0f6b43f80ed144b79bfe704e4)
      #06 pc 000000000022e184  /vendor/lib64/libsec-ril.so (Thread::ThreadMain(void*)+172) (BuildId: 74ae01d0f6b43f80ed144b79bfe704e4)
      #07 pc 00000000000e6f20  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) (BuildId: 27147c78d1670fec7bce21c48e84eb70)
      #08 pc 00000000000850c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 27147c78d1670fec7bce21c48e84eb70)
```

I have developed a mobile application using Expo React Native 48 SDK. Created the Google Play Build using EAS and uploaded to playstore. But the application was rejected because it has a stability error. I need help to understand what caused the error ?

I tried updating the dependencies that I used in my project but still it failed.

Comment: I solved it @EbrahimKarimi Were you able to solve yours

Comment: Yes i just cleaned the build and rebuild it and it fixed the issue @EnockMale